# Test driven software design of an Android application

Tags: android

Concerning validation of an `Android` application, are there any points for writing lines of codes to be simply testable (both `manual` and `automatic` tests) ?

Comment: are you asking: is there any point of writing tests for Android apps?!

Comment: No, I meant writing code in a way to be able to write test for the code simply, sometimes we may write code in a way that makes it hard or impossible to write test for the code which is the subject of **test driven software design**

Comment: you can maintain code in layers , separate classes for api calls , separate classes for views that you are using at multiple places

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, testing small applications is not a top priority (since they suppose to be implemented fast and quickly and most of the time they serve a small purpose) and you can be skeptical with that since not writing test can save a bit of time. therefore no need to write the code in a way that is testable too.

But remember a few things:

1. Writing a testable code is a skill that an intermediate developer must have.
2. A testable code will lead to a maintainable code and that is very important for applications that have a future (almost all of them)
3. adding features is a lot easier when you have tests on.
4. Building a team and even passing the code to another person to maintain/add new features is a lot easier with a testable app.
5. As far as I know, in android testable code means architected code and architecture is compulsory for almost all applications.
6. Testable codes need to be following coding standards like SOLID Principles

   7. Maintain code in layers, such as separate classes for Api calls and make separate classes for views that you are using at multiple places in Application
   8. Don't write too much code in activities, and don't make functions too long that you have to deep search for piece of code after some time.
   9. Try to write comments frequently, so that some one can understand your code easily

thus try to learn how to write testable and do your best to write test. It will pay off before you know it

**Update**
to run your test automatically you can use a CI server.
there are lots of option on how to create and configure one. but there are plug and play options as well.
but for further details you can read official [Android Developer Doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/continuous-integration)

hope I answered your question

Comment: You know when the test cases are too many, whenever a change in code is needed all the test cases should be retested again and it needs a robot to test them, would you please explain how you automatically test an Android app ?

Comment: if the answer helped you at all please consider upvoting or accepting it

Comment: Thanks for the info but sorry I don't think this is answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

The following link dirrects us to `Test Driven Development`:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals